# Using DojoToolkit parser and JSPDoj

Tags: jsp, dojo

I've tried to implement the 'Layout with Dijit' tutorial http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/dijit_layout/
as a JSP.

My code JSP code is:

```
<html xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page">
  <jsp:output doctype-root-element="HTML" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" />
  <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
  <jsp:directive.page pageEncoding="UTF-8" />
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Demo: BorderContainer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.1/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" media="screen" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.1/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async:true, parseOnLoad: true"></script>
    <script>
      require([ "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dojo/parser"]);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body class="claro">
    <div id="appLayout" class="demoLayout" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design: 'headline'">
      <div class="centerPanel" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region: 'center'">
        <div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="edgePanel" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region: 'top'">
        Header content (top)
      </div>
      <div id="leftCol" class="edgePanel" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region: 'left', splitter: true">
        Sidebar content (left)
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The HTML generated by the jsp engine (Tomcat 7.0) is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Demo: BorderContainer</title>
    <link media="screen" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.1/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script data-dojo-config="async:true, parseOnLoad: true" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.1/dojo/dojo.js"/>
    <script>
      require(["dijit/layout/BorderContainer","dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dojo/parser"]);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body class="clark">
    <div data-dojo-props="design: 'headline'" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" class="demoLayout" id="appLayout">
      <div data-dojo-props="region: 'center'" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" class="centerPanel">
        <div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div data-dojo-props="region: 'top'" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" class="edgePanel">
        Header content (top)
      </div>
      <div data-dojo-props="region: 'left', splitter: true" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" class="edgePanel" id="leftCol">
        Sidebar content (left)
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When this HTML is rendered by the browser (FireFox 10.0.2) then nothing happens. The defined layout is not applied. Even the required modules are not loaded. Only the 'claro.css' and the 'dojo.js' are loaded.

Can anybody give me a hint what's wrong with the generated HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your rendered HTML. Your body element defines a class of `clark` instead of `claro`. You also need to use an end-tag with the `script` element *(I'm not qualified to tell you why, it just needs to be there to work)*.

The other issue was a little harder to see. According to the "Setting Sizes" section on [this](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/layout/BorderContainer.html) page, you also need to include a definition for the width/height of the `BorderContainer` element. As an in-place fix, I added the following to the `head` section of your page:

```
<style>
 body, html { width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; }
 #appLayout { width:100%; height:100% }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Adding the CSS and a closing <script> tag solved the problem.